# Problems with extjs treepanel renderer

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I would like to slightly modify the default tree panel renderer. So in the first step, I try to just call the default tree panel renderer. Unfortunately, this doesnt work.

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('FMSGui.view.FMSFeatureTypeTreePanelColumn',
{
  extend:   'Ext.tree.Column',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  flex:1,
  renderer: function(v1)
  {
      return this.callParent(v1);
  }
}
);
```

The code for the TreePanel looks as follows:

```
Ext.define('FMSGui.view.FMSFeatureTypeTreePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title: 'Feature Types',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: null,
    displayColumn:null,
    constructor: function(config)
    {
        this.displayColumn=Ext.create("FMSGui.view.FMSFeatureTypeTreePanelColumn");
        this.columns=[this.displayColumn];
        this.store=Ext.create("FMSGui.store.FMSFeatureTypeTreeStore");
        this.store.load();
        this.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
    },
    rootVisible: true,
    lines: true, 
    useArrows: true 
    });
```

I always get the error message:

XTemplate evaluation exception: this.callParent is not a function

It works by the way, if I remove the renderer part.

Any idea what goes wrong here?
Thanks for any remarks.

Comment: noone else any idea? Still could not solve it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Its a scope issue. In `renderer`'s closure `this` is not reference to `FMSGui.view.FMSFeatureTypeTreePanelColumn` (its actually reference to a window), thus there is no `callParent` property.

Try to read this articles: [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), [this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

*If you describe what exactly you want to achieve with `return this.callParent(v1);` ill try to help you wtih some code / fiddle.*

Comment: ah thanks a lot, i would like to do internationalization in the renderer, thus, change this.callParent(v1); to this.callParent(translate_map[v1]); sorry, accidently clicked on edit instead of add comment, could someone just delete the  part i wrote above. I am not allowed to do it myself as it seems.